# Check String Against SQL Injection in C#, MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, security, sql-injection

I'm looking for libraries that can validate string against SQL injection. Something like that code:
http://aspdotnetmyblog.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-check-string-against-sql.html.
That code check if the string is containing sequences like "@@", "kill" etc. (more than 60 that kind of checks)

That is probably one of the simplest ways of checking that but maybe there are dedicated libraries that can handle that better way. I need something like that, of course, the best will be if that will be free.
I'm fully aware that the proper way of preventing SQL injection can't be based only on that kind of validation and other ways like parametrized queries should be used. Still,  I need a way to validating input parameters even if that will be not 100% accurate.

Comment: Using SQL parameters is free. Are you creating SQL queries inside a stored procedure?

Comment: There's no fool-proof way to do this. You should use parameterised SQL queries instead.

Comment: that app is very specific, it is some type of analytic tool and already there is a significant amount of SQL that needs to be rewritten. Probably I will writer program that will do that automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you should follow OWASP guidelines.

https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection
https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Use sqlmap python tool on your web app to test attacks. 
http://sqlmap.org/